# Pagination with Spring-Data : PageRequest leaking into REST Controller

Tags: mongodb, rest, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm working on a REST API based on Spring-Boot with a MongoDB database. The application uses a Controller > Service > Repository approach. I'm currently working on implementing a paginated endpoint:

```
/api/clients?range={offset}-{limit}

eg. /api/clients?range=0-25 (retrieves entities 0-24)
```

My problem is that, in order to build a 'Content Range' response and in order to distinguish between 200 'OK' and 206 'Partial Content' responses (depending on whether the request retrieves all the entities or not), I need to retrieve info like the total number of entities from a Page object. So I'm building a PageRequest in the Controller which gets passed to the Service and through to the Repository. I end up with something along these lines :

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(params = { "range" })
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllClients(
        final @RequestParam(value = "range", required = false) QueryRange queryRange,
        final HttpServletResponse response) {

    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_RANGES, "client " + MAX_CLIENTS);

    if (queryRange.getCount() > MAX_CLIENTS) {
        throw new ForbiddenRangeException("client", MAX_CLIENTS);
    }

    Integer offset = queryRange.getOffset();
    Integer limit = queryRange.getLimit();

    Integer count = limit - offset;
    Integer page = offset != 0 ? offset / count : 0;

    PageRequest request = PageRequest.of(page, count);

    final Page<Client> clients = clientService.getAllClients(request);

    final HttpStatus status = (queryRange.getOffset() == 0 && clients.isLast())
            ? HttpStatus.OK
            : HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT;

    final String contentRange = String.format("%d-%d/%d",
            queryRange.getOffset(),
            queryRange.getOffset() + clients.getContent().size() - 1,
                clients.getTotalElements());

    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_RANGE, contentRange);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(clients, status);
}
```

How could one structure this in order to prevent such leaking ?

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I've amended the original question. Basically, in this use case is there a way to avoid spring-data concepts such as Pageable from leaking all the way up to the controller ?